# How to setOnNavigationItemListener on BottomNavigationView in android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I use kotlin-android-extension and I can call `bottomNavigationView` id from layout file to kotlin file. I can use `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {})`, but whats next?

As far as I know in Java, there is another function called `onNavigationItemSelected`, but I can't find it in kotlin.

this is the example code I want to use in Java but cannot write it in kotlin.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_favorites:

                case R.id.action_schedules:

                case R.id.action_music:

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use the java to kotlin converter in android studio

Comment: this app already use kotlin from the start, so I can only write kotlin right? not write Java in kotline file.

Comment: just realize that you can copy paste it and auto convert it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this format of code:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_favorites -> {
        }
        R.id.action_schedules -> {
        }
        R.id.action_music -> {
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: What does that "true" stand for?

Comment: Sorry, the "return" expression is mistakenly removed from code during the last edit. 
I've fixed it now.
Thanks.
@Chris

Comment: when i set return true this show errors message, only false keep error clean.? what is that..

Comment: It's not working with the `return true`, you have to add `else -> true` to the when block. Otherwise you will get the error "When expression must be exhaustive, add necessary else branch"

Comment: @Glory how to set one default menuitem among the items?

Comment: @Chris return true to display the item as the selected item.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 9):

You can use below code

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            var selectedFragment: Fragment = A()
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_item1 -> selectedFragment = A()
                R.id.action_item2 -> selectedFragment = B()
                R.id.action_item3 -> selectedFragment = C()
            }
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment)
            transaction.commit()
            return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
```

Comment: Why we have to add @setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener after return word ?

Comment: wrong! the when is executed only once when the listener is set, so it's not equivalent to the java code in the question

Answer (score 7):

use must add annotation for return the lambda only

```
 bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.home -> {}

            R.id.group -> {}

            R.id.profile -> {}
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: wrong! the when is executed only once when the listener is set, so it's not equivalent to the java code in the question

Answer (score 4):

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_favorites -> { }
                R.id.action_schedules -> { }
                R.id.action_music -> { }
            }
            true
        }
```

note that last line seems to miss the return keyword, but

> The last expression in a lambda is considered the return value:

from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Moreover, @setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener creates a

```
local final fun <anonymous> (it: Menuitem) : Boolean
```

wrapping what follows, so in some answers this will have the effect of executing the when block only when the listener is set (only one time), and the callback will be just a return true statement.

Answer (score 4):

This is my code using the new Navigation component.
Let me know if you need help with nav ui.

```
bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.mainFragment)
                }
                R.id.search -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.searchFragment)
                }
                R.id.inapppurchases -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.inappPurchasesFragment)
                }
                R.id.settings -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
                }
            }
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> return boolean in each block because setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener expects return type

```
fun initViews() {
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_menu_media -> {
                true
            }
            R.id.action_menu_tag -> {
                true
            }
            R.id.action_menu_home -> {
                true
            }
            else -> {
                true
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin:
use setOnItemSelectedListener

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
        when (item.itemId) {
             R.id. ... -> {
                Add your code
             true
        }
        
        else ->
            true
    }
```